# Used a token to secure API without authentification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**Objective**

When a person creates a resource (no need to connect), she receives a unique token, which she must then transmit to each request she sends for information about her resource.

**Question**

There is a simple way to do that with Spring? Indeed, all tuto I found and read used an authentification with username and password.

**Already tried**

My first idea was to create a token at the end of `POST` methods (store it into database), put it into  each `GET` requests and check if `requestToken == databaseToken`.

However, I don't think that's the best way to do it.

So, can you help me and advise me to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.

Using the @SessionAttributes annotation:

The first time our controller is accessed, Spring will instantiate an instance and place it in the Model. Since we also declare the bean in @SessionAttributes, Spring will store the instance.

You will get it inside controller's handler method thru @ModelAttribute.

Or, you can try this route:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String handler(HttpSession httpSession) {
    httpSession.getId(); //this will give you unique identifier that you can set back to object that you send to front end and can share the same ID between requests. 
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId--